# Visual Studio C++ Adding Deployable Content(Entire Folder)

Tags: c++, windows, deployment, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to add resource files to my Visual Studio C++ project, but my images do not seem to be copying correctly during the build step. When developing within a C# environment, this was easily achieved by right clicking on the resource file(an image or what have you) and editing the "Copy to output directory" option. This option does not seem to exist within the C++ environment. Here is a picture of the C# environment to better illustrate the option that I am looking for:
[image]

I tried doing roughly the same thing within the C++ environment but, like I said, the option simply does not exist. Instead it only gives a "content" option, with a "yes" or "no". The tool tip says that this is related to a deployment resource, however the resource is not deployed during the project build. I would also like the entire folder to be copied upon build; here is another picture:
[image]

Does anyone know how I can replicate this within a C++ environment?

***EDIT***

I tried using a post-build event script, but nothing appeared in the output directory. I am trying to copy the "Resources" folder, which I show in the second image. Here is the script that I am using:

```
xcopy "$(ProjectDir)Resources" "$(TargetDir)Resources" /e /y /i /r
```

Did I do something wrong in that? I don't even see any errors in the build log.

Comment: For the Post build process I looked at the paths and everything looks ok. So the question is, why is the folder not being copied over?

Comment: Nevermind...apparently Visual studio decided that it wanted to start copying the folder for some reason. (Sigh).

Answer (score 0):

Your post build script worked for me.  Yes, it is disappointing that the C++ project solution does not make doing so easier.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31251970)

Answer (score -1):

Add the project output to the installation project as content Files

Comment: I have the same problem. I don't understand Jack's answer and I don't have an answer of my own. Does anyone have an answer??

Comment: I believe he's referring to the `Content` field in the Properties window of the file (F4). You can also access it from the Properties dialog via right-click -> Properties. The former is True/False and the latter is Yes/No.

Comment: However, this had no effect for me (on C++ Cross Platform).